# Difficulty with jQuery and input keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am making a simple JavaScript enhanced list. I want it to be a list of inputs, each with an 'Add' and 'Remove' button. If the user clicks 'Add', a new `li` will be added. If the user clicks 'Remove', that `li` will be removed.

It works fine, except for hitting "enter" in an `<input>`. Currently, it always causes the `Remove.click` event handler to fire, unless there's only one item in the list. I'm not sure why. How can I suppress this?

Here is the complete jQuery. My attempt to fix the "enter" issue is commented out, and it doesn't work. I suspect that I could be designing this code better; if you see an improvement I'd love to hear it.

```
function make_smart_list(list)
{
    var ADD_CLASS = 'foo-widget-Add';
    var REMOVE_CLASS = 'foo-widget-Remove';

    var jq_list = $(list);
    jq_list.parents('form').submit(function() {
        return false;    
    });

    function refresh_handlers() {
        jq_list.find(sprintf('.%s, .%s', REMOVE_CLASS, ADD_CLASS)).unbind('click');
        // jq_list.find('input').unbind('submit');
        // 
        // jq_list.find('input').submit(function() {
        //     var jq_this = $(this);
        //     var next_button = jq_this.nextAll('button');
        //     if (next_button.hasClass(ADD_CLASS)) {
        //         next_button.nextAll('button').click();
        //         return;
        //     }
        //     
        //     if (next_button.hasClass(REMOVE_CLASS)) {
        //         return false;
        //     }
        //     
        // });

        jq_list.find("." + REMOVE_CLASS).click(function() {
            var jq_this = $(this);
            jq_this.parent().remove();
            refresh_handlers();
            return false;
        });

        jq_list.find("." + ADD_CLASS).click(function() {
            var jq_this = $(this);
            if (jq_this.prevAll('input').val() == '') {
                return;
            }

            jq_this.parent().clone().appendTo(jq_this.parent().parent());
            jq_this.parent().next().find('input').val('').focus();
            jq_this.removeClass(ADD_CLASS).addClass(REMOVE_CLASS);
            jq_this.text('Remove');
            refresh_handlers();
            return false;
        });
    }

    refresh_handlers();
}
```

(`sprintf` is another script I have.)

**Update**: The markup looks like:

```
<ul id="id_bar" class="foo-widget-list">
    <li><input value=""><button class="foo-widget-Remove">Remove</button></li>
    <li><input value=""><button class="foo-widget-Add">Add</button></li>
</ul>
```

This is part of a form that contains other components, but all I'm concerned about is this part.

Script to actually activate the list:

```
$(function() {
    $.each($('.foo-widget-list'), function(index, item) {
        make_smart_list(item) 
    });
});
```

**Update 2**: Setting the keydown as follows works to prevent problems with inputs by "Remove" buttons:

```
    jq_list.find('input').keydown(function(e) {
        var next_button = $(this).nextAll('button');
        if (e.keyCode == ENTER_KEYCODE && next_button.hasClass(REMOVE_CLASS)) {
            return false;
        }
```

But pressing enter while focused on an input by an "Add" button still results in the `remove.click` handler being fired.
        });

Comment: I think I can provide a solution if you provide the related markup.

Comment: @Rosarch It might be useful if you posted the HTML code.

Comment: @Rosarch I cannot optimize your jQuery code if I don't know the HTML structure.

Comment: @Sime Vidas and @mVChr the html is posted. Sorry for omitting that initially.

Comment: @Rosarch Shouldn't both list items have a Remove button?

Comment: @Sime Vidas no, the second one is a place for the user to input a new entry.

Answer (score 2):

In the [keup docs](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/), it actually has a specific example for detecting the hitting of the 'enter' key.  Here's an excerpt, slightly modified to (hopefully) make it easier to put into your code:

```
$([element_selector]).keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == '13') {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
  // other keyup code here
});
```

You'll want to put this in a handler that you put on an element when you create it, but this basic idea should work okay.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('input').keydown(function(e) {    
    if (e.keyCode == 13) { return false; }
});
```

You just track the ENTER key and kill the event if it is pressed.

Note that the `submit()` method is used only on `<form>` elements, not its fields.

Answer (score -1):

No jQuery needed. Just overwrite the `onsubmit` event of all the forms in the page.

```
var inputs=document.all.tags('form')||document.getElementsByTagName('form');
for(x=0;x<inputs.length;x++){
    inputs[x].onsubmit=function(){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: (deleted off-topic comment chain)