# Maxlength for text area doesn't work in IE

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to limit the number of characters entered in a textarea as shown:

```
<div>
 @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.StudentName, new { @maxlength = "1000" })
</div>
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome but the maxlength attribute doesn't work in IE. How do I do that??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125482/how-to-impose-maxlength-on-textarea-in-html-using-javascript

Comment: @TimMedora: So why not mark the question as a duplicate?

Comment: @leppie - because last time I searched for a maxlength script that worked in all cases, I ended up writing my own. The post I linked to is over 18 months old; there may be a better solution out there but I figured it would give the OP somewhere to start at least. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `maxlength` attribute is not standard for [`<textarea>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.7) in HTML 4.01. It is [defined in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-button-element.html#the-textarea-element) though but I guess IE doesn't implement it. To make it work across all browsers you could use javascript. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1125521/29407).

Comment: It does work in IE10 according to this chart from wufoo: http://wufoo.com/html5/attributes/03-maxlength.html

Comment: @Sharon, IE10 is not RTM yet.

Comment: Yes it does work in IE10+. Only IE9 and less is an issue. It is a very good solution for the problem!!!

Answer (score 12):

Here is my jQuery based solution. Works well in IE9, a little wonky in IE8.

```
// textarea event handler to add support for maxlength attribute
$(document).on('input keyup', 'textarea[maxlength]', function(e) {
    // maxlength attribute does not in IE prior to IE10
    // http://stackoverflow.com/q/4717168/740639
    var $this = $(this);
    var maxlength = $this.attr('maxlength');
    if (!!maxlength) {
        var text = $this.val();

        if (text.length > maxlength) {
            // truncate excess text (in the case of a paste)
            $this.val(text.substring(0,maxlength));
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hjPPn/

link for IE8: http://jsfiddle.net/hjPPn/show

#### Native Browser Support

Also, in case you're wondering which browsers do support `maxlength`: https://caniuse.com/#search=maxlength

Answer (score 3):

You can use javascript as well, which is way easier:

```
<textarea  name="question" cols="100" rows="8" maxlength="500px" onKeyPress="return ( this.value.length < 1000 );"></textarea>
```

Comment: @MatthiasDailey If you're using jQuery, my answer handles pasting. It could probably be refactored to pure JS.

Comment: Why do you have a px for maxlength? That's not what it's for.

Comment: Burying Javascript in your HTML might seem 'easy' to you, but I hope I never have to maintain your code!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Jquery - for eg, if you want to restrict the length to 48

```
$("textarea").keypress(function(e){
    var lengthF = $(this).val();

    if (lengthF.length > 48){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: this fails when the user tries to press delete or backspace. The user will be stuck after reaching the limit