# javascript onkeypress limit characters when pasting

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, aurelia, maxlength

I've a textarea with keydown.trigger in Aurelia:

```
<textarea name="description" keydown.trigger="handleKeypress($event, $event.target.value)" 
value.bind="desc" ></textarea>
```

In .js file then I have this code:

```
handleKeypress(event,newValue) { 
  let max = 3413;
  let valueSize = new Blob([newValue]).size; 
  if (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57 || event.key === "Backspace") {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    event.onpaste = function(e){
        e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain').slice(0, max);
};
    if (valueSize>= max) {return false;} 
  }
  return true;
}
```

So this shouldn't allow more characters than 3413 bytes in textarea as in DB I have limits in bytes, so I can't use simple maxlength here.

This code works fine, it doesn't allow to enter more characters. It also doesn't allow pasting text with CTRL+V but only if the limit is reached.

**The problem is, when the limit is NOT reached yet and someone pastes a long text via CTRL+V or right mouse click - paste. Then the content is pasted and it is over limit in textarea.**

I want to achieve that textarea doesn't show more chars than the limit

UPDATE: I also tried to use the mentioned solution from another thread via `e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain').slice(0, max);`

but this does nothing in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript prevent copy/pasting beyond character limit in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573561/javascript-prevent-copy-pasting-beyond-character-limit-in-textarea)

Comment: Why not just have `return valueSize<max;` since you return true in all other cases

Comment: you mean instead of last return true put return valueSize<max; ? This did not worked

Comment: @NamigIsmayilov not really a duplicate as the mentioned solution doesn't work in Chrome and there is maxlength used which I can't use here.

Comment: can you clarify the logic of why you need to handle paste event only when keypress? Can't they be separate?

Answer (score 3):

what's the problem with using maxlength?

I tried it and it works for me:

```
<template>
     <textarea name="description" maxlength.bind="max" value.bind="desc"></textarea>
</template>
```

And in the viewmodel:

```
export class Test {
  max = 3;
}
```

I tested this in codesandbox and works fine. See https://codesandbox.io/embed/4zy4k5r3k7

Comment: well, I did not think that I can bind also the maxlength, so thanks for this. But the problem is, I have no maxlength value, because I only know, the max bytes that DB can accept. So I can't just define maxlength as a fixed number as it may vary according to 2-bytes chars etc. Maxlength must be in chars, not bytes

Comment: I get it. My best approach would be to set the max size of the string as the DB bytes divided by two. Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, I think I will go this way, so in that case I can use maxlength with half size of DB bytes as you suggested  (and I don't expect that user will use all characters 2-bytes) so it should be far enough.